# C26816 warning on returning shared_ptr.get()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, smart-pointers

C26816 reads: "The pointer points to memory allocated on the stack"

VS gives this warning on returning of shared_ptr.get(), but I was under the impression that the returned pointer pointed to the managed object on the heap and thus is valid as long as the smart pointer is referenced?

I haven't yet encountered any issues with this yet, but I want to confirm whether or not I should heed this warning, or if it's another eccentricity of Visual Studio.

Example:

```
int* test()
{
    auto a = std::make_shared<int>(5);
    someVector.push_back(a);
    return a.get(); // warning here
}
```

Notably it doesn't appear to happen on unique_ptr.get() when I tested it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes, I'll edit it to make it clear that is not what I'm asking. Apologies for being unclear.

Comment: This looks like VS is wrongly assuming that because the object `a` goes out of scope and `a` is on the stack, then a pointer provided by `a` would equally be pointing to an object on the stack.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Even so, the error makes no sense. The pointer does not point to memory allocated on the stack.

Comment: Trusting vs studio static analysis…

Comment: When `a` is destroyed, the thing that `a` points to will also be destroyed.  The pointer you're returning is invalid.

Comment: @MarkRansom by definition a shared pointer is incremented on copy. In the example I provided, the copy would keep the underlying data alive. I was under the impression that a.get() returned the pointer to the *heap* memory for the underlying data, meaning while the 'a' copy is technically dead, the integer persists and thus a.get() is still valid.

Comment: @CalvinSoueid your thinking is correct. The compiler is simply *warning* you about a *potential* issue that doesn't actually apply in your case.